# Core Data vs. Dictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, nsdictionary

Is there any performance difference between querying using object for Key on an NSDictionary vs. a Fetch Request on Core Data? is there any performance difference in storing them the same ways?

Please note, I'm only asking about performance, not about code design or organization.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An NSDictionary is stored entirely within RAM memory.  Core Data could be stored in a SQLite database which could cause a bit of latency that you would not get from just an NSDictionary.

Comment: Note: it doesn't have to be a SQLite database. There are a variety of ways of storing persistent data with Core Data, each with its own level of nonzero latency. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html.

Comment: Yes, but there is no situation that I can see where CoreData would outperform NSDictionary.

Comment: Oh no, I absolutely agree. I was just making the point that he is not limited to SQLite.